# MAVEN - add 3rd party software

Tags: java, maven, minecraft

Is there a way to set maven up to make it possible to use 3rd party software?
I am trying to add the dependecy Spigot (minecraft server jar) to my project, but I want to work on it with some friends, and I want it too automatically update, if one of us decides to change the pom.xml.

So what I have next is:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

but now I have to do something with maven, but I have no clue how?
Isn't there a way so it will automatically install it from that website I have put at the repository thing?

I liked the idea of maven, but if this is not possible it is kinda useless for what I want XD

I hope someone knows how it will automatically update it, because for all I have searched I got nothing :/

Comment: What IDE are you using? When I did the same - adding Bukkit dependencies to the pom in Eclipse - Eclipse automatically installed all the required dependencies for me after about 10 minutes of downloading. There was no progress bar or GUI to show that, only the jar dependency showing up out if nowhere when it was completed.

Comment: I am using Netbeans as IDE, but I have waited for almost 2 hours :P

Comment: "I want it too automatically update, if one of us decides to change the pom.xml" what does this even mean? update how?

Comment: Like if someone wants a newer version for example for Spigot, they simply change the POM file, and anyone who updates their project over github, will download the new spigot automatically

Comment: Welp, I fixed it XD, you need to install maven... Netbeans automatically has maven (not everything I suppose) but for these kind of things you will need to install the full thingy XD

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option, that might help you to update the snapshot on daily basis. Not sure what other options are, you might want to check on that sometime.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```